# Calculating e number C#

Tags: c#, math

I am trying to calculating e number by that

```
e = 1 + (1/1! + 1/2! + 1/3! + ..)
```

User going to select number of trials on that form.
[form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTuZ3.png)

```
 int trialNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(trialNumberForm.Value, 0));
        int factorial = trialNumber;
        float factResult = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i < trialNumber; i++)
        {

            for (int b = 1; b < i; b++) //calculates x! here.
            {
                factorial = factorial * b;


            }
           factResult = factResult + (1 / factorial);
        }
        factResult++;
        MessageBox.Show(factResult.ToString());
```

It calculates the result 1 which ever number you selected! I've tried to change variable type to float from double but that didn't fix it. How to act on numbers by formula which I wrote above?

Comment: Which variable type did you try to change? Note that `1 / factorial` is currently going to be integer arithmetic... also note that factorials will overflow `int` pretty quickly...

Comment: It is called "Integer division", look it up. Split `factResult = factResult + (1 / factorial);` in to `var temp = (1 / factorial); factResult = factResult + temp;` and see what the value `temp` is and what the type of `temp` is too.

Comment: `factorial` is a positive integer so `1/factorial` is always 0. I think changing it to  `1.0/factorial` will help.

Comment: I'm assuming this is an exercise in implementing an algorithm, considering [Math.E](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.e?view=netframework-4.7) exists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have no need in factorial (with its *integer division* and *integer overflow* problems) at all since

```
  1/(n+1)! == (1/n!)/(n+1)
```

You can implement `e` computation as easy as

```
  double factResult = 1; // turn double into float if you want
  double item = 1;       // turn double into float if you want

  for (int i = 1; i < trialNumber; ++i)
    factResult += (item /= i);

  ...

  MessageBox.Show(factResult.ToString());
```

Outcomes:

```
   trial number | e
   -------------------------------
              1 | 1
              2 | 2
              3 | 2.5
              4 | 2.666666... 
              5 | 2.708333...
             10 | 2.71828152557319
             15 | 2.71828182845823 
             20 | 2.71828182845905
```

Comment: Drives me nuts to see people calculating factorials in Taylor series when your way is the obvious answer.  Nice demonstration of quadratic convergence, too.

Comment: @duffymo: This is still the Taylor series. Convergence however is super-linear (independent of the implementation) as the error of the degree n partial sum is bounded by 2/(n+1)!. One could compare if computing exp(0.5)^2 or exp(0.25)^4 is faster, even when accounting for the extra squaring multiplications.

Comment: I know very well that this is a Taylor series.  Convergence is quadratic, like I said.  You obviously don't understand my comment.

Answer (score 1):

As @kabdulla and @ScottChamberlain said, you are doing integer division where you need a float division :

```
for (int b = 1; b < i; b++) //calculates x! here.
{
    factorial = factorial * b;
}
factResult = factResult + (1 / factorial);
```

Should be

```
for (int b = 2; b < i; b++) //calculates x! here.
{
    factorial = factorial * b;
}
factResult = factResult + (1.0 / factorial);
```

Plus I started the `for` loop at `b = 2` because multiplying by 1 is useless.